# Apple Sign-In is not working on Flutter App

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications, apple-sign-in

I launched a Flutter app on iOS and it was published successfully with Apple Sign-In implemented. After 1 month I tried to publish a new version with updates(to be specific I added push notifications capability-more details below) and I got rejected because Apple Sign-In was buggy. It gives these errors.

```
[core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7034 "(null)"

flutter: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)
```

I searched for these errors and I tried every possible solution I was able to find.

1. I reset the provisioning files.
2. I tried on Debug and Release modes.
3. I recreated the key from the Apple developer portal.
4. I checked my capabilities and everything is there. Sign-In capability is added on all modes.

So, I believe I tried everything I found on the web but still couldn't resolve the issue. I tried to get more info about the error with debugging but I was only able to get what I showed above.

**Important:** The error started after I added Push Notifications on the app via Firebase Cloud Messaging. To be specific I added these capabilities in order to set up Push Notifications on my app;

1. **Push Notifications**
2. **Background Modes** (Background Fetch, Remote Notifications)

**Important 2:** When I tried to sign-in via the first version of my app downloaded from the App Store, it logs in but it only fetches the email address. It doesn't fetch the name and surname they come null. This functionally was working successfully like 2 weeks ago.

The package I used for implementing Apple-Sign In - https://pub.dev/packages/apple_sign_in

I'm actively trying to resolve this issue. So, I will reply as fast as possible. I'm looking for help! Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're doing this from a real device then? Because I read that error is common on Simulators

Comment: I got the error both on Simulator and Real-Device. But when I tried the old version I have on App Store it worked like I explained on **Important 2**.

Answer (score 0):

> Important 2: When I tried to sign-in via the first version of my app downloaded from the App Store, it logs in but it only fetches the email address. It doesn't fetch the name and surname they come null. This functionally was working successfully like 2 weeks ago.

You only get full name and e-mail address when your app prompts the user to sign in with apple (i.e. on first authorization, and any time after that you want them to re-authenticate).

If your code is expecting a full name and e-mail every time, then that's probably your issue.

Are you using the backend at all, for instance, to verify the user's `id_token` or sending the `authorization_code`?

*Note: I know nothing of Flutter, so my help can only extend to the Apple side of it ;)*

Comment: I actually didn't know that I only got one chance to fetch the name and mail address. The thing is that I don't expect the name and mail address over and over again. I save them on the database and fetch them from there. I was deleting the user info from my db to test Apple Sign-In. Also, the problem is not causing from my end I believe. I saw a lot of person having this issue in the last 4-5 days. See it in here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656932?login=true&page=1#627310022

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway... I'm very grateful.

Comment: No problem. I'm assuming you also tried the steps they suggest on the forums, like removing the Simulator from your devices, or entering the two factor authentication code

Comment: I actually did not try those solutions. Because I thought It won't change the situation for Apple Review Team. But I will try to see what happens :/